# jqtouch - panels appear on page, class="back" not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch

I'm trying to get a demo working that was used in J. Stark's webinar on Safari Books Online (still available for viewing).

I think I've followed the code example correctly, but the class="back" objects used to return from the "blog", "contacts", "settings" and "about" panels do not work, though the correct address shows in the nav area at the base of the browser window when I hover the mouse over the respective link.

The panels-- which should slide in and out when called by their respective class"arrow" elements-- appear on the main page, nor do they animate correctly.

Browser is Safari 5.0.3(6533.19.4); jquery-1.3.2; jqtouch freshly downloaded from the jqt website.

Obviously I'm missing something simple. I'd sincerely appreciate anyone's help who sees what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for considering my question. View the app and source code (use view source in your browser) [here](http://web.fastermac.net/~reidjam7/jqtouch/jqtouch/#jqt).

Sat 8 January 2011: 1 48 AM

UPDATE in response to JS's comments:

Most humble thanks for your note. Didn't want to impose on your server, so the URL for jqtouch.min.css points to a version on my server @ fastermac.net. There's something further amiss, I believe. On load, page still shows the  elements that should be invisible until called by clicking class="arrow" elements. Animations not yet wiggling. Did get them to wiggle at one point, but "flip," for instance, landed then on a black page-- not the targeted panel. Probably something obvious, but I'm missing it after some considerable due diligence. Again, thanks for your note. Any further illumination would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code, and the first thing I noticed was that the url to jqtouch.min.css is invalid. That file needs to be available for animations of any kind to take place.

It also looks like you're using an older version of jQT. This should be fine but it wouldn't hurt to upgrade to the latest and greatest. Click the big DOWNLOADS button here for the most recent version of jQTouch:

https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch

Cheers!

j